# SQL Server CE database not Affected for insert and update

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I am writing C# Forms application and using normal SQL Server CE database (`.sdf`).

What happened is that no changes are written to the database. For example when trying to add a row, it will never show up in the database table. But when do the selection, it seems that it does exist !

What is the problem here ?

Comment: Please be more specific about where you are seeing and not seeing the DB changes.  Also some code would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `|DataDirectory|` or simply a relative path then you have 2 copies of the SDF file in your project folders.

Your application is using the one in `..\Root\bin\debug`.

Your tools (VS server explorer) are looking in `..\Root`.

Comment: How to make it write to that copy ?

Comment: Use a ConnectionString with a fixed path. Also set `Copy to Output` to `never`.